# Dependency property not updating usercontrol ui

Tags: wpf, silverlight, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have a usercontrol which has a couple of textblocks on it

```
<UserControl x:Class="Tester.Messenger"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         x:Name="myUserControl"
         >  
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=myUserControl,Path=Header,Mode=TwoWay}" Foreground="LightGray" FontSize="11"  Margin="3,3,0,-3"/>
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding ElementName=myUserControl,Path=Message, Mode=TwoWay}" Foreground="White" FontSize="16" Margin="3,-5"/>
```

In my code behind I have two dependency properties that I'm binding the above textblocks Text property to.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HeaderProperty", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl), new PropertyMetadata("header"));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MessageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MessageProperty", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));


 public string Header
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(HeaderProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(HeaderProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public string Message
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(MessageProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(MessageProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

When I create a object of my UserControl and I change the Header and Message properties and place the control in an ItemControls items collection,  then these aren't being reflected in the control. The control just displays the default values for the Header and Message.

```
 Messenger m = new Messenger();
        m.Header = "colin";
        m.Message = "Download File ?";
        iControl.Items.Add(m);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first parameter in your call to `DependencyProperty.Register` is incorrect:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HeaderProperty", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl), new PropertyMetadata("header"));
```

should be:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Header", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl), new PropertyMetadata("header"));
```

The string should be the name of the property as it will appear in XAML, that is without the "Property" suffix. Same goes for your message `DependencyProperty`.

Comment: When I first started doing WPF - this got me far too many times!

Comment: Yeah thanks very much. Silly mistake to make. Was looking at it way too long and couldn't figure it out. Thanks again